# How to get following sibling of an etree._Element

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml, xml.etree

I am iterating over elements which I find in a xml file like so:

```
for elem in fileasxml.xpath("//elementname[some condition]"):
    do something
```

Now instead of `do something` I'd like to write the element I have found plus the first following-sibling to a file. Now I know how to write to a file, what I don't know is how to get the following sibling.

I've seen the `getnext()` method but it doesn't work since the element I'd like to get is not in `elem`.

Same reason I can't use `elem.xpath()`

Any ideas ?

Comment: what about `itersiblings()`? http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itersiblings

Answer (score 3):

Okay I was wrong. I made a mistake adding the element I found to a new structure before finding the following sibling.

getnext() actually works !

Comment: Could you improve your answer please... I don't get it xD